# Linear Solve of FLOPS

Tags: matlab

[image]

```
%% Part A
% max value of N for an NxN matrix of floating point numbers
% 8GB of ram
Mb = 1600;
nmax = floor(sqrt((Mb*1024*1024)/160)); 

%%Part B
A = rand(nmax); % random nmax x nmax matrix
B = rand(nmax); % random nmax x nmax matrix

tic
prod = A*B;
prod_time = toc

% Total flops
Totflops = (2/3)*(nmax).^3;
flops = Totflops/prod_time % flops/sec

% Theoretical flops per second 2.4GHz Processor
tflops = 2.4*10^9 * 4 %flops per second

%% Part C 
Nvec = logspace(100,nmax);

for  i = Nvec
  A = rand(i);
  b = rand(i,1);
  tic
  x = A\b;
  lutimes(i) = toc;
end

%y = logspace(nmax,100);

%%Part D
loglog(N,lutimes,'.')
hold on
```

I am getting an error about maximum variable size being reached and don't know how to correct it. Also I am aware that I have yet to finish the graphs but struggling to finish part c beforehand. Do I need to change how my for loop functions?

Comment: Why are you using two accounts? Your other account → https://stackoverflow.com/users/9371530/

Answer (score 2):

The first problem we encounter is with `Nvec = logspace(100,nmax)`. The most glaring issue here is that `logspace(a,b)` returns values which span `[10^a, 10^b]`. In your case I doubt that you have enough RAM to store `10^(2*nmax) = 1e6238` floating point values (which is about 6000 orders of magnitude larger than the `DBL_MAX`!) The other issue is that `logspace` will almost certainly return non-integer values, so you need to round the results in order to use those values to define matrices. Try this instead:

```
Nvec = floor(logspace(log10(100),log10(nmax)));
```

You've also got an issue with the loop indexing. You're storing values into `lutimes(i)` when `i` is supposedly a value between `100` and `nmax`. This doesn't make sense. Instead iterate through the indices of `Nvec` as follows...

```
lutimes = zeros(size(Nvec));
for  idx = 1:numel(Nvec)
    A = rand(Nvec(idx));
    b = rand(Nvec(idx),1);
    tic
    x = A\b;
    lutimes(idx) = toc;
end
```

Finally, `loglog(N,lutimes,'.')` should be `loglog(Nvec,lutimes,'.')` since `N` doesn't exist.